# Defining coordinate system for every GeoDataFrame (shapefile) in list

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, iteration, geodataframe

I am looking to set a coordinate system for every GeoDataFrame in a list of them. So I need this:

```py
gdfs[0].crs = "EPSG:6668"
gdfs[1].crs = "EPSG:6668"
```

And so on but iteratively. I tried:

```py
([gdfs.crs = "EPSG:6668"] for file in gdfs)
```

And:

```py
for file in gdfs:
    gdfs.crs = "EPSG:6668"
```

But not working, any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for gdf in gdfs:
    gdf.crs = "EPSG:6668"
```

Or

```
for i in range(len(gdfs)):
   gdfs[i].crs = "EPSG:6668"
```